# Photo LIKE, COMMENTS NOSql database Design

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, social-graph

I am trying to implement in LIKE and COMMENT system like Instagram and Facebook in DynamoDB

I have 3 tables, user, photo and photo_likes

user table and photo table have user_id and photo_id keys.

and for photo_likes table, I have photo_id as a key and liked_by column where I store user_id as list.

So, If the photo_id 1 is liked by user_id 10, 35, I store it as:

```
| photo_id | liked_by |
|     1    |  {10,35} |
```

I am really confused if it is the right way to do it? or should I just insert a new row whenever their is a new like.

```
| photo_id | user_id  |
|     1    |    10    |
|     1    |    35    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide the advantage and disadvantage of the above approaches. You may need to choose the correct approach based on your **Query Access Patterns** required for your application.

**Approach 1:**

```
| photo_id | liked_by |
|     1    |  {10,35} |
```

**Advantage & Suggestion:-**

- My suggestion would be to store the `liked_by` as `NS` or `SS` rather than List. So that it will not have duplicates.
- All the `liked_by` are present in the same item. This will help during retrieval and showing the results on GUI if required

**Disadvantage:-**

- Can't create index (in case if required) on non-scalar data types (SS, NS or List)
- Be aware of the maximum size (400 KB) of the item in DynamoDB. This may impact the data model if number of likes increase to unexpected values which could impact the size of the item

**Approach 2:**

```
| photo_id | user_id  |
|     1    |    10    |
|     1    |    35    |
```

You can define `photo_id` as partition key and `user_id` as sort key.

**Advantage:-**

- You can create index on user_id if required
- You can sort the data by user_id (if defined as sort key)
- No need to worry about 400 KB item size

**Disadvantage:-**

- Counting the `likes` should be done at client side by iterating the values. In approach 1, you can use some `array.length` to get the `likes` count
- The number of items in the query result set would be high which could be difficult to deal with. This point depends on whether you have an use case to get the list of photos and its `likes` count or any similar sceanrio

Comment: what about create a third table with the counting like, I mean when you give a like to a item then your insert that like into the like table and this table triggers a stream to update the third table count_likes, so for retrieval purpose it would be faster, isn't it ?

Comment: Multiple tables is an anti-pattern in NoSQL. You should ideally have 1 table per application. That could cut your read cost by half or even more if indexes are done smartly. Also, you'll be able to support 10+ access patterns with only 1-2 global indexes.

Comment: And also, approach 2 doesn't have to be so expensive to count votes, just maintain a meta item in table with total like count. Could be done in application layer or with Lambda and DDB stream if it doesn't have to be 100% accurate, otherwise use transactions (people tend to make too big deal out of eventual consistency which is usually <1ms in case of DDB and accuracy - error margin would probably be <0.1%, unless you have some huge issues with application server).